# How do I change .NET version in Xamarin for a MonoMac exe?

Tags: .net, xamarin, monomac

There doesn't seem to be a place to do this. Usually I go to Options -> General for libraries and then I can change the Framework version... strange.

Comment: Why do you need to change to an older .NET version other than .NET 4.5?

Comment: I was going from .NET to .NET 4.5 to support certain libraries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, a couple of months ago I ran into this same issue; I checked the .csproj file of a project that had this setting visible to see what the deal was, and the issue went away after I copied over the setting:

```
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```

at the end of the first property group.

Comment: That's the answer I ended up with. Thanks for putting it in.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change that, it's determined by the Xamarin version you are using, currently (a subset of) .Net 4.5

TargetFrameworkVersion mentioned in the previous answer is Android framework version, not .Net framework version.